# Getting API Data to show on a webpage with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm trying to get data from https://wttr.in/?format=j1 to show on a webpage. I'm very new to Javascript so I hoped this would be easy but I'm struggling to get it to work, what am I doing wrong?.

```
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content=
    "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
 
<body>
    <p id="temp"></p>
</body>
<script>
  const api_url = "https://wttr.in/?format=j1";
 
  async function getWeather() {
   
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
 
    const data = await response.json();
    
    const weather = data.results[0].current_condition[0];
    
    let { temp } = weather.temp_C;
    
    document.getElementById("temp").href = "temp:" + temp;
 
  getWeather();
  
</script>
 
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you got a syntax error there (check the browser console, it will tell you about those!) - your function does not have a closing `}` anywhere.

Comment: Second, the JSON you will be receiving, does not contain a `results` property. You want to access `data.current_condition[0]` directly.

Comment: Third, `let { temp } = ` - those curly braces here make no sense, remove them.

Comment: And finally, trying to set the `href` attribute of a paragraph, that makes little sense. Make that last line `document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "temp:" + temp;`

Comment: Done all those changes and it works perfectly! thanks for the help with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments from CBroe (thanks for the help) the main issues with my code were a few things.

- No closing bracket
- Not accessing the correct part of the JSON array
- Not setting the element correctly

The working code looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content=
    "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
 
<body>
    <p id="temp"></p>
</body>
<script>
  const api_url = "https://wttr.in/?format=j1";
 
  async function getWeather() {

    const response = await fetch(api_url);
 
    const data = await response.json();
    
    const weather = data.current_condition[0];
    
    let temp = weather.temp_C;
    
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "temp:" + temp;
}
  getWeather();
  
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not parsing the json response correctly. The `data` does not have any results array, it is an object.

So to get `current_condition` you need to do something like this:

```
    const currentCondition = data.current_condition[0];
```

Also, to get `temp_C` this is wrong:

```
let { temp } = weather.temp_C; //WRONG
// reason is that this statement means that `temp_C` is an object, and it contains `temp` property, which is not the case here. Because temp_C is a string.
```

So to get `temp_C` you need to simply do this:

```
    let temp_C = currentCondition.temp_C;
```

Plus, worth mentioning here that if you are using the `temp_C` only for displaying purposes and not intending to reassign any value to it, then its better to use `const` instead of `let`

So it would become:

```
    const temp_C = currentCondition.temp_C;
```

And if you want to use 'destructuring' you need to write it like this:

```
    const { temp_C } = currentCondition;
```

Also your function is missing the closing paranthesis `}`.